# adding a namespace when using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

This is what I am after

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<ws:Test>
    <ws:somename2>somevalue2</ws:somename2>
    <ws:make>
        <ws:model>foo</ws:model>
        <ws:model>bar</ws:model>
    </ws:make>
</ws:Test>
```

This is my current code

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<Test/>', 0, false, 'ws', true);
$xmlTest->addChild("ws:somename2", "somevalue2", 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make = $xmlTest->addChild('ws:make', null, 'ws');
#$make->addAttribute('name','Ford');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'foo', 'ws');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'bar', 'ws');
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
print_r($xmlTest->asXML());
```

but it outputs

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<Test>
    <ws:somename2>somevalue2</ws:somename2>
    <ws:make>
        <ws:model>foo</ws:model>
        <ws:model>bar</ws:model>
    </ws:make>
</Test>
```

As you can see the ws: is missing from Test

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SimpleXML has an unusual quirk where the namespace prefixes are filtered from the root element.   I'm not sure why it does this.

However, a workaround I've used has been to basically prefix the prefix, so that the parser only removes the first ones, and leaves the second

```
$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<xmlns:ws:Test></xmlns:ws:Test>', LIBXML_NOERROR, false, 'ws', true);
$xmlTest->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:ws', 'http://url.to.namespace');
$xmlTest->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
```

This seems to work for me, though I'm interested to understand why SimpleXML does this exactly.

Comment: So adding a prefix to the prefix fixed the issue :)

Comment: Did you find any other solution than this workaround?

Comment: A more correct method can be found here, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808578/simple-xml-add-namespaced-child

Comment: Note that this adds the "namespaces" as attributes, not namespaces, though the result when serialized with [`SimpleXMLElement->asXML()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.asXML) is equivalent. "xmlns:" is part of the [local part](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-LocalPart) of the attribute name, rather than a prefix. Note they appear in `$xmlTest->attributes()`, but not `$xmlTest->getDocNamespaces()`.

You can also use any prefix, not just "xmlns".

Comment: No namespaces are being "filtered from the root element" in the code in the question, the OP just didn't add any - their root element is `<Test />`. Specifying the namespace argument `'ws'` when *reading* that element won't magically cause the element to be in a namespace when written back out.

Answer (score 16):

## The Problem

The problem with this code is in the very first line:

```
$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<Test/>', 0, false, 'ws', true);
```

Before doing anything else, let's output this as XML:

```
echo $xmlTest->asXML();

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test/>
```

That makes sense, we got out what we put in.

The manual is rather vague on what the `$ns` argument does, but in this case it is not doing anything useful. What it does is set the context for *reading* the XML, so that `->foo` refers to `<ws:foo>` and `['bar']` refers to `ws:bar="..."`. It doesn't do anything to change the structure of the XML itself.

## Setting a Root Namespace

To set a namespace on the root element, we just have to include it in our string defining the root element:

```
$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<ws:Test xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" />');
echo $xmlTest->asXML();

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ws:Test xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"/>
```

So far so good...

## Setting Namespaces on Children

Next, let's sanity check what the code in the question actually outputs (I've added some whitespace to make it more readable):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Test>
   <ws:somename2 xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">somevalue2</ws:somename2>
   <ws:make xmlns:ws="ws">
        <ws:model>foo</ws:model>
        <ws:model>bar</ws:model>
   </ws:make>
</Test>
```

OK, so this document contains two namespace declarations:

- `xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"` on the `somename2` element
- `xmlns:ws="ws"` on the `make` element, which is then inherited by the `model` elements

What happens if we add our corrected root element?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ws:Test xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
    <ws:somename2>somevalue2</ws:somename2>
    <ws:make xmlns:ws="ws">
        <ws:model>foo</ws:model>
        <ws:model>bar</ws:model>
   </ws:make>
</ws:Test>
```

Cool, so the `somename2` element now inherits its namespace definition from the root element, and doesn't re-declare it. But what's wrong with the `make` and `model`s? Let's compare:

```
$xmlTest->addChild("ws:somename2", "somevalue2", 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make = $xmlTest->addChild('ws:make', null, 'ws');
```

That third argument is supposed to be the **namespace URI**, not just the prefix. So when we gave it as `'ws'`, SimpleXML assumed we wanted to declare the actual namespace URI as `ws`, so added an `xmlns` attribute to do so.

What we actually wanted was all the elements to be in the same namespace:

```
$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<ws:Test xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" />');
$xmlTest->addChild("ws:somename2", "somevalue2", 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make = $xmlTest->addChild('ws:make', null, 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
#$make->addAttribute('name','Ford', 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'foo', 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'bar', 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
echo $xmlTest->asXML();

<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ws:Test xmlns:ws="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
    <ws:somename2>somevalue2</ws:somename2>
    <ws:make>
        <ws:model>foo</ws:model>
        <ws:model>bar</ws:model>
   </ws:make>
</ws:Test>
```

Great, we've got our desired output!

## Tidying Up

But that code looks rather ugly, why do we have to repeat the URI everywhere? Well, as far as SimpleXML is concerned, there's not much choice: the same prefix can mean different things in different parts of the document, so we have to tell it what we want.

What we *can* do is tidy up our code using a variable or constant for the namespace URI, rather than writing it out in full each time:

```
define('XMLNS_WS', 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');

$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement('<ws:Test xmlns:ws="' . XMLNS_WS . '" />');
$xmlTest->addChild("ws:somename2", "somevalue2", XMLNS_WS);
$make = $xmlTest->addChild('ws:make', null, XMLNS_WS);
#$make->addAttribute('name','Ford', XMLNS_WS);
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'foo', XMLNS_WS);
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'bar', XMLNS_WS);
```

There's nothing special about the name `XMLNS_WS` here, and it could equally be a variable, a class constant, or a namespace constant. The code runs exactly the same, it's just a little easier on the eye.

Comment: Actually you don't need to repeat the same namespace to children elements, they will inherit the same namespace specified from parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlTest = new \SimpleXMLElement('<ws:Test></ws:Test>', LIBXML_NOERROR, false, 'ws', true);
$xmlTest->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:ws', 'http://url.to.namespace');
$xmlTest->addChild("ws:somename2", "somevalue2", 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/');
$make = $xmlTest->addChild('ws:make', null, 'ws');
#$make->addAttribute('name','Ford');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'foo', 'ws');
$make->addChild('ws:model', 'bar', 'ws');
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.