# SimpleXMLElement two name spaces in a single element

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to make this xml using SimpleXMLElement:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="Signature620397">

 $signature = $invoice->addChild('ds:Signature', null, 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
 $signature->addAttribute('xmlns:etsi', 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#');
 $signature->addAttribute('Id', 'Signature620397');
```

Later in the xml i need to reference the etsi namespace, but i could not find a way

```
<etsi:QualifyingProperties Target="#Signature620397">
```

Is there anyway to do this? Or that would be the limitations of SimpleXMLElement

Comment: If you aren't required to use `SimpleXMLElement`, I suggest you give [`DOMDocument`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) a whirl, instead. The API is much more consistent and well understood.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927567/adding-a-namespace-when-using-simplexmlelement/43561160#43561160) useful.

A namespace is ultimately identified only by its full URI; the `etsi` prefix might change meaning halfway down the document. The way SimpleXML has been designed, you have to mention this full URI every time you add a namespaced element or attribute.

On the other hand, you *don't* need to manually add the `xmlns:etsi` attribute; SimpleXML will add that automatically when you first use the namespace.

In other words, you have to write:

```
 $xml->addChild('etsi:QualifyingProperties', null, 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#');
```

And SimpleXML will generate this if it's the first time you've mentioned that namespace:

```
<etsi:QualifyingProperties xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" />
```

Or just this if the prefix `etsi` is already defined with the right value at that point in the document:

```
<etsi:QualifyingProperties />
```

Obviously, it's tedious to write out the full URI over and over, but that can be resolved simply by having a variable or constant in your code with a name that means something to you, like this:

```
define('XMLNS_ETSI_132', 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#');
$xml->addChild('etsi:QualifyingProperties', null, XMLNS_ETSI_132);
```